# Client.tree.sync is not getting recognized

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and when I wanna sync commands so its easier for me to use it but if i use it its not getting recongized my orblem is the `client.tree.sync()` thats not getting recognized. [here as you can see its white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYAif.png)

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.tree.sync
    activity = discord.Game(name=presencestatus, type=2)
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd, activity=activity)
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Bot is currently running.")
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Made by ChriSs#0001")
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate i dont

Answer (score 1):

When calling "await client.tree.sync" you arent executing anything. The correct way of calling it is to use "await tree.sync()". Adding a parenthesis creates a courotine and the await makes it actually run.

For the type checking I don't know how you configured vscode so I cant say much about the reason, but Pycharm is correct with its warning.

Based on the comment, I have decided to provide a small sample.

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

#  Command tree created.
tree = discord.app_commands.CommandTree(client)


#  Command added to the tree.
@tree.command(name="test", description="test function")
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="This works!")
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    #  Sync tree with discord.
    await tree.sync()
    print("Commands synced.")

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: i get a error when adding it like this and do you know a video that shows how to set it up riht? 
NameError: name 'tree' is not defined

Comment: Without knowing what you are trying to do, it's hard to help you. Do you have any interaction based commands you have set up? Did you create a tree and add commands that need syncing up? Do not just write it here as a comment, edit the post and provide more details. The [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=tree#discord.app_commands.CommandTree) docs about the command tree should help you with the issue if you wish not to do so.